# Error undefind offset: 0 PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema en el programa `Racktables` cuando ejecuta esta función:

```
function sortEntityTags (&$cell)
{
    global $taglist;

    if (! is_array ($cell['etags']))
        throw new InvalidArgException ('cell[etags]', $cell['etags']);
    $cell['itags'] = array();

    foreach ($cell['etags'] as $tag_id => $taginfo)

       foreach ($taglist[$tag_id]['trace'] as $parent_id)
       {
           $cell['itags'][$parent_id] = $taglist[$parent_id];
           unset ($cell['etags'][$parent_id]);
       }
```

}

En la pagina me da el siguiente error:

> Argument 'input' of value '(array)' is invalid (ID column missing).

Y revisando los logs de apache obtengo este error:

> Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/pruebasgesti/inc/functions.php on
>   line 1647

Llevo ya varios días intentando identificar el error pero no doy con el.

Un saludo y muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: puedes indicarnos cual es la linea 1647 de tu archivo `functions.php` ?

Comment: la linea seria esta:`foreach ($taglist[$tag_id]['trace'] as $parent_id)`

Comment: entonces te esta indicando que el array `$cell['etags']` es un array con claves numericas, y que en la primera iteracion del bucle de la linea 1647 el indice 0 de `$taglist[$tag_id]` no existe. Da la sensacion que `$taglist` no existe, o cuando se ha llamado en ese momento esta definido como vacio. Puede darse ese caso en tu aplicacion?

Comment: En este caso las tablas a las que hacen referencia parecen estar bien y no tener nada raro, ¿necesitas que te de algún dato mas?, gracias por adelantado.

Comment: por favor, añade antes del primer foreach lo siguiente: `print_r($cell['etags']);` y `print_r($taglist[0]);` para que veamos que valores tienes, a ver si eso arroja un poco de luz a este misterio :)

Comment: Buenas, esto es el principio de lo que pinta, `Array ( )
Array ( ) Array ( [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [tag] => desarrollo [parent_id] => 2 [color] => [description] => [user] => [time] => ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 12 [tag] => GestProc [parent_id] => 10 [color] => [description] => [user] => [time] => ) ) Array ( [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [tag] => desarrollo [parent_id] => 2 [color] =>`

Comment: edita la pregunta y añadelo con formato, que asi no se puede entender mucho...  :)

Comment: Buenas, al final lo solucione borrando unos registros de la tabla que estaban a cero y ya funciona correctamente, gracias.